# How to used Xcode task in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: ios, xamarin, azure-pipelines

I have a Xamarin CI process set up in Azure Pipelines.
Due to my recent changes, I need to use iOS 13.0 to compile my code.

In my `azure-pipelines.yml` I have the following code:

```
   - task: Xcode@5
     inputs:
      sdk: "iphoneos13.1"
      xcodeVersion: "/Applications/Xcode_11.1.app"
      actions: 'build'
```

Sidenote: I am using `poolvmImage: 'macos-latest'`

I took the Xcode task from [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/xcode?view=azure-devops).

On [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/macos/macos-10.14-Readme.md) it looks like ALL Mac machines have iOS 13 SDK installed.

...but when I run

```
- task: CmdLine@2
     inputs:
      script: 'xcodebuild -showsdks'
```

from my yml file it is displaying the following output:

```
Script contents:
xcodebuild -showsdks
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
[command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /Users/vsts/agent/2.158.0/work/_temp/11b07ed3-faf4-4917-a9ea-3c1dc52aa96f.sh
iOS SDKs:
    iOS 12.4                        -sdk iphoneos12.4

iOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - iOS 12.4            -sdk iphonesimulator12.4

macOS SDKs:
    macOS 10.14                     -sdk macosx10.14

tvOS SDKs:
    tvOS 12.4                       -sdk appletvos12.4

tvOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - tvOS 12.4           -sdk appletvsimulator12.4

watchOS SDKs:
    watchOS 5.3                     -sdk watchos5.3

watchOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - watchOS 5.3         -sdk watchsimulator5.3
```

The question is:
how to force Azure Pipelines to use iOS 13 and Xcode 11 to build my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are facing should be due to our image deployment delays. For my region(**East US 2**),if I execute the command

```
xcodebuild -showsdks
xcodebuild -version
```

And below is the `iOS` and `Xcode` info about the `Hosted macOS 10.14` on my region.

[image]

According to the info you shared, seems the hosted agent used by the region where your org is located have not been deployed with these latest upgrade. So, even with command to pick up iOS 13 or other SDK still could not succeed because of none SDK exists.

Most time, the deployment process would has some delay because of different regions. Please pay some times to waiting for the deployment job finished. It will be fully deployed to all regions in the latest two weeks.

If you are hurry for building and deploy your app with these SDKs, here has a temporary work around can for you use: install the **private macOS pre-release agent** by reference to this link: 
[Pre-release agent 2.159.1](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases).

Comment: Thanks @Merlin Liang - MSFT for your comment. I am pretty in a hurry but I think it will take less time to build version manually. Thanks again!

Comment: @lawiluk, Since its not security to share your org info in SO, I could not help you check the process from our backend. If you are hurry and concern about this, you could raise a ticket [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=4d7c8158-200d-893b-5161-06d00803fd9c). Our engineer would help you check the process and when will it deployed onto your region.